# Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"] Error even after Running Virtual Box Startup

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

When running vagrant up I still get the following error:

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

```
Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleCreate(HandlerArg*, int, int*)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

I've tried to run:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist
```

But to no effect.

Tried to use when I used to have 4.2.x VirtualBox.

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart
```

Comment: Other information:

vagrant-berkshelf (1.3.4)
vagrant-cachier (0.5.0)
vagrant-omnibus (1.1.2)
Vagrant 1.3.5
Berkshelf (2.0.10)

Answer (score 0):

What does your Vagrantfile look like?

Can you run `VBoxManage hostonlyif create` from the host without issues?

Also, what are you trying to accomplish here? If you just want a host-only network, look here: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html